# How to push multiple objects into a React state variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, state

I have a state variable that stores an object which contains the array `invitees` as a value:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    date: '',
    location: '',
    invitees: []
})
```

I have an array containing multiple objects:

```
users = [
    { _id: 'id1', name: 'name1', email: 'email1' },
    { _id: 'id2', name: 'name2', email: 'email2' },
    { _id: 'id3', name: 'name3', email: 'email3' }
]
```

I'd like to be able to push each of these objects into the `values.invitees` array.

I can do this for individual objects using a function like this:

```
const addInvitee = (user) => {
    setValues({ ...values, invitees: [...values.invitees, user] })
}
```

But my problem is when I try to add multiple objects at once.

I have tried mapping through them like this:

```
users.map((user) => {
    addInvitee(user)
})
```

And also using a `for loop`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < users; i++) {
    addInvitee(users[i])
}
```

However both these attempts result in only the last object element in the array being added.

Is anyone able to help me understand why this is happening and what I can do to fix it. Many thanks.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: `setValues({ ...values, invitees: [...values.invitees, ...users] })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem

That is because `values` reffered inside the `addInvitee` is the same initial `values` (empty array) not the updated `values`.

```
const addInvitee = (user) => {
    setValues({ ...values, invitees: [...values.invitees, user] })
}
```

#### Solution

To avoid the stale value issue you should use the callback function of setter of the `useState` hook.

Try like below:

```
const addInvitee = (user) => {
  setValues((prevValues) => ({
    ...prevValues,
    invitees: [...prevValues.invitees, user]
  }));
};
```

In this case, `prevValues` is always guaranteed to be the updated values.